# How to select object in dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a City class

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

and Ride class.

```
public class Ride
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public City From { get; set; }
    public List<City> To { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to load cities, pass it to view, show them in dropdownlists and POST data back to controller? Best would be if I could add more than one City to To column.
I have found [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) but I have no experience with JavaScript. Can I pass to options only JSON etc or could it be a list of cities from database.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a view model, especially if you want to select multiple cities at once. For example:

```
public class RideViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }

    public int FromCityId { get; set; }
    public List<int> ToCityIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CityChoices { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that there's no `List<City>` property on the view model. Instead, there's `ToCityIds` which will store the selected id values from the list box and `CityChoices` which will be used to populate the list box. You can't post full `City` objects from a list box, only simple types like `int`. So, on POST you'll use the values from `ToCityIds` to lookup up the `City` instances from the database. The same goes for your `From` property on your entity.

Now, in your controller:

```
private void PopulateCityChoices(RideViewModel model)
{
    model.CityChoices = db.Cities.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.Id,
        Text = m.Name
    });
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new RideViewModel();
    PopulateCityChoices(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RideViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Create new `Ride` and map data over from model
        var ride = new Ride
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            DateAndTime = model.DateAndTime,
            From = db.Cities.Find(model.FromCityId),
            To = db.Cities.Where(m => m.ToCityIds.Contains(m.Id))
        }
        db.Rides.Add(ride);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Must repopulate `CityChoices` after post if you need to return the form
    // view again due to an error.
    PopulateCityChoices(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

Finally in your view change the model declaration to:

```
@model Namespace.To.RideViewModel
```

And then add your `From` select list and `To` list box:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FromCityId, Model.CityChoices)

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ToCityIds, Model.CityChoices)
```

You can use the same choices for both, since they're both selecting cities.